# Solana Program - on / off switch by Knox Hutchinson and Jonathan Barrios

Tags: solana-program

I'm following the tutorial from Know in adept [solana on / off program][1]
[1]: https://learn.adept.at/forked/solana-blockchain-development/skill/creating-a-solana-program-with-anchor

I started the code by using

```
init projectname --javascript
```

From what the video explains, doing do is a way to scaffold the program with everything needed.
The lib.rs file looks like this

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
pub mod flipper2 {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        let switchAccount = &mut ctx.accounts.switchAccount;
        switchAccount.state = true;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn flip(ctx: Context<Flip>) -> Result<()> {
        let switchAccount = &mut ctx.accounts.switchAccount;
        if switchAccount.state {
            switchAccount.state = false;
        } else {
            switchAccount.state = true;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 16 + 16)]
    pub switchAccount: Account<'info, SwitchAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub systemProgram: Program<'info, System>
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Flip<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub switchAccount: Account<'info, SwitchAccount>,
}

#[account]
pub struct SwitchAccount {
    pub state: bool,
}
```

and the js file

```
const anchor = require("@project-serum/anchor");
const assert = require('assert');
const {SystemProgram} = anchor.web3;

describe("flipper2", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  const program = anchor.workspace.Flipper2;


  it("Creates a flip account", async () => {
    // Add your test here.
    const SwitchAccount = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    console.log(SwitchAccount.publicKey.toBase58())
    await program.rpc.initialize({
      accounts: {
        switchAccount: switchAccount.publicKey,
        user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
      },
      signers: [switchAccount]
    });
    const baseAccount = await program.account.switchAccount.fetch(switchAccount.publicKey);
    console.log('Flip 1:', account.results)
    assert.ok(baseAccount.state);
    _baseAccount = baseAccount;
  });

  it ("Flip it", async () => {
    baseAccount = _baseAccount
    await program.rpc.flip({
      accounts: {
        switchAccount: baseAccount.publicKey;
      }
    })

    const account = await program.account.switchAccount.fetch(baseAccount.publicKey);
    assert.ok(account.state == false);
  })
});
```

This is the error when running `cargo build`

```
error: a non-optional init constraint requires a non-optional system_program field to exist in the account validation struct. Use the Program type to add the system_program field to your validation struct.
  --> programs/flipper2/src/lib.rs:29:9
   |
29 |     pub switchAccount: Account<'info, SwitchAccount>,
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate`
 --> programs/flipper2/src/lib.rs:5:1
  |
5 | #[program]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `__client_accounts_initialize` in the crate root
  |
  = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `try_accounts` found for struct `Initialize` in the current scope
  --> programs/flipper2/src/lib.rs:5:1
   |
5  | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `Initialize<'_>`
...
27 | pub struct Initialize<'info> {
   | ---------------------------- function or associated item `try_accounts` not found for this
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `try_accounts`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `anchor_lang::Accounts`
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Initialize<'_>: anchor_lang::Accounts<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> programs/flipper2/src/lib.rs:5:1
   |
5  | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `anchor_lang::Accounts<'_>` is not implemented for `Initialize<'_>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `anchor_lang::Accounts<'info>`:
             AccountLoader<'info, T>
             Box<T>
             CpiAccount<'info, T>
             CpiState<'info, T>
             CreateNonceAccount<'info>
             CreateNonceAccountWithSeed<'info>
             Ctor<'info>
             Flip<'info>
           and 26 others
note: required by a bound in `anchor_lang::context::Context::<'a, 'b, 'c, 'info, T>::new`
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0599]: no method named `exit` found for struct `Initialize` in the current scope
  --> programs/flipper2/src/lib.rs:5:1
   |
5  | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Initialize<'_>`
...
27 | pub struct Initialize<'info> {
   | ---------------------------- method `exit` not found for this
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `exit`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `anchor_lang::AccountsExit`
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0432, E0599.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `flipper2` due to 5 previous errors
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can more often than not solve (or be hinted towards) your problem by reading what errors the compiler spits out. Debugging with  print statements, checking the documentation or searching for similar issues online can also be helpful in understanding and resolving the error.

Starting with the first one:

```
error: the init constraint requires the system_program field to exist in the account 
validation struct. Use the Program type to add the system_program field to your 
validation struct.
  --> programs/so_help/src/lib.rs:29:9
   |
29 |     pub switchAccount: Account<'info, SwitchAccount>,
```

This error tells you that `system_program` field is missing, this account  is necessary when creating new accounts, as that can only be done by the system program. This is not the case in your context as you have:

```
pub systemProgram: Program<'info, System>,
```

For your program to compile change the above line to:

```
pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
```

After compilation there are still remaining warnings, reading the first one it states that:

```
variable `switchAccount` should have a snake case 
convert the identifier to snake case: `switch_account`
```

Rust convention is that you use `snake_case` for local variables. Full naming convention is [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/style/naming/README.html). This applies only to Rust/Solana, on the client side contract IDL is generated with the `camelCase` so the accounts you would provide in your tests would be `systemProgram` or `switchAccount`.

The link you provided requires an account to view it. If you are looking for a good resources, I recommend [Solana Playground](https://learn.adept.at/forked/solana-blockchain-development/skill/creating-a-solana-program-with-anchor). It doesn't require sign-up, has many interactive examples and it even mines devnet SOL for you.